# how can I return row information on a failed insert/update in SQL Server?

Tags: t-sql, error-handling

Suppose I am doing an insert or an update on a table.  So in the BEGIN CATCH/END CATCH I can define a variable to ERROR_MESSAGE() and get back my error message:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'columnname', table 'Table'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Is there any way I could return say the primary key of the offending record or anything to identify which row actually failed?  I rollback the transaction on failure so it's not like I can look at the 'last' record to see the next one which has the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible AFAIK due to the fact you're not truly working on one record at a time.

Of course for inserts there are no primary keys yet assigned.  If you really need that granular level of detail the best advice I can offer is to insert/update one row at a time so you know for sure which one threw the error.

Comment: somehow I was afraid that might be the answer for no other reason that I'd hate to think i've been doing this stuff for a LONG time and never came across it...

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I check my data for things like that before I try to do an insert. Don't swtich to working one record at a time. Instead write something that will chcek for data that is not there for required fields. If you put the information on what failed into a table variable at the time of the check, it will still be available after the rollback and then you can insert it into a permanent error table to see what records were causing the problem.

Comment: By the fact the poster is using TRY / CATCH in T-SQL I assume the data is already all server-side, thus inserting one row at a time I don't see as being any worse then rolling a load back later.

Comment: actually the data is being calculated, some of the calculations involving several fields.  Granted I could easily wrapper everything but I was hoping more for something I could use as a diagnostic since the fields are never supposed to be NULL so it would help be validate my calculations.

Comment: Use of try catch doen't have anything to do with processing one vice a group of rows. It is just error handling.